# (Dis)Prove $x \le z+y-d$ given $x \le e+f-a, x \le z+f-c, x \le e+y-b, d \le b+c-a$

Tags: inequality

we are given the following constraints for x
$$x \le e+f-a$$
$$x \le z+f-c$$
$$x \le e+y-b$$
$$d \le b+c-a$$

We need to prove(or disprove) that

$$x \le z+y-d$$
where $x, y, z, a, b, c, d, e \in \mathbb{R}$
I tried for some examples and it seems that the relation to be shown holds given the constraints. But I don't know the formal way of proving. Any starting point, hint will be helpful.

Comment: Pick numbers for $x,y,z,d$ that make the inequality false and then try and fill in the gaps for the other variables to make sure all the constraints are still true.

Comment: Take $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=-2$, $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=0$, $d=0$, $e=1$ and $f=2$.